# PHP Array or SQL error iterating over foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have what I suspect is either an array error or a mysql query error. I have printed all the variables in the function, they return the correct result, and tried the same query in phpmyadmim which returns the correct result.

The use case is pretty simple

1. Get `$_GET['gameID']` and query DB
2. Get returned result from 1st query and query DB for a 2nd time with week number and sport.
3. return an array with all results form second query

### PROBLEM

The current function is only returning the last row of the table instead of returning all rows.

**Picture of table**

[image]
**Output result**

[image]

**Code**

```
function displayTeamsByGameID($gameID)
{
    global $db;
    //now prevents late submissions
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE gameID = :gameID";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':gameID', $gameID);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $games =  $stmnt->fetch();
        print $weekNum = $games['weekNum'];
        print $sport = $games['sport'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE weekNum = :weekNum AND sport = :sport";
    $stmnt= $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $weekNum);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':sport', $sport);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if($stmnt->rowCount() > 0){
     $matches= $stmnt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
             $match[] = array('gameID' => $match['gameID'], 'weekNum' => $match['weekNum'], 'gameTimeEastern' => $match['gameTimeEastern'], 'homeID' => $match['homeID'], 'visitorID' => $match['visitorID'], 'sport' => $match['sport'], 'venue' => $match['venue'], 'tournament' => $match['tournament'], 'spread' => $match['spread']);

                 }//foreach
            }//statment weekNUm Sport
    }//statment gameID
        if (!isset($match)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $match;
}//function
```

If anyone could give my code a quick scan and or provide some advice it would much appreciated.

Comment: `I have printed all the variables in the function, they return the correct result`
Can you please confirm this. The result you posted in the question has the same row (last row) twice, one as indexed and other as associative array. Data is same.

Comment: you don't have a column named `sport` unless you're not showing us the full image, same thing goes for a few others in your loop.

Comment: use https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and php's error reporting. You'd of seen it for yourself.

Comment: Hi @Vivek thanks for taking the time to read. The variable output for second  for second query is dislayed if you click on he `print_r()` output image. It reads `round = 1 & sport = rugby` I havent uploaded full pic of DB please see edit for full pic. Many thanks

Comment: Hi @FunkFortyNiner (they gonna be a good team next year) I edited the image showing full table. Please can you clarify what ` same thing goes for a few others in your loop` means...? Thanks

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner OH `You'd of seen it for yourself` you mean I have an error in mysql statment, I'l lhave a quick look.

Comment: `'sport' => $match['sport'], 'venue' => $match['venue'], 'tournament' => $match['tournament'], 'spread' => $match['spread']` those arrays. I don't see column names of the same in the image you posted. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: No I re-uploaded the image. They are in the table. Please see new complete image.

Comment: I think the issue could be because of the way you are using the $match variable. Its used in the foreach like this foreach ($matches as $match) but then inside the loop you set $match[] to an array of data then return it at the end of the function. I think you should use a different variable name for the array for are trying to build and return that at the end of the function.

Comment: @dougtesting.net well spotted thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$match` variable since you have used the same variable in the `foreach` statement and within the `foreach` body for creating the result array. Use a different variable. See the code below. I have used a new variable `$result` for the result.

```
function displayTeamsByGameID($gameID)
{
    global $db;
    //now prevents late submissions
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE gameID = :gameID";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':gameID', $gameID);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $result = array();
        $games =  $stmnt->fetch();
        print $weekNum = $games['weekNum'];
        print $sport = $games['sport'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE weekNum = :weekNum AND sport = :sport";
    $stmnt= $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $weekNum);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':sport', $sport);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if($stmnt->rowCount() > 0){
     $matches= $stmnt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
             $result[] = array('gameID' => $match['gameID'], 'weekNum' => $match['weekNum'], 'gameTimeEastern' => $match['gameTimeEastern'], 'homeID' => $match['homeID'], 'visitorID' => $match['visitorID'], 'sport' => $match['sport'], 'venue' => $match['venue'], 'tournament' => $match['tournament'], 'spread' => $match['spread']);

                 }//foreach
            }//statment weekNUm Sport
    }//statment gameID
        if (!isset($result)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
}//function
```

Comment: Damn! Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayTeamsByGameID($gameID)
{
    global $db;
    //now prevents late submissions
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE gameID = :gameID";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':gameID', $gameID);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $games =  $stmnt->fetch();
        print $weekNum = $games['weekNum'];
        print $sport = $games['sport'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bru_schedule WHERE weekNum = :weekNum AND sport = :sport";
    $stmnt= $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $weekNum);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':sport', $sport);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if($stmnt->rowCount() > 0){
     $matches= $stmnt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
             // 【don't reassign value to $match, it's confused! Use an new variable name】
             $ret[] = array('gameID' => $match['gameID'], 'weekNum' => $match['weekNum'], 'gameTimeEastern' => $match['gameTimeEastern'], 'homeID' => $match['homeID'], 'visitorID' => $match['visitorID'], 'sport' => $match['sport'], 'venue' => $match['venue'], 'tournament' => $match['tournament'], 'spread' => $match['spread']);

                 }//foreach
            }//statment weekNUm Sport
    }//statment gameID
        if (!isset($ret)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $ret;
}//function
```